# PWL constraints efficiency

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, gurobi

So, I'm trying to optimize MILP, which has PWL constraints. I use `gurobi`, and when I'm optimizing model without those constraints, gurobi finds solution in a *matter of seconds*. The problem is when I try to add PWL constraints, performance drops significantly. When I added only 419 out 4072 PWL constraints, gurobi took several minutes two solve the model, and when I added all of them, it couldn't find feasible solution (which must always exist) in several hours. PWL function I use has 11 breakpoints and has no jumps. I can't post all code (there's too much) so here super general outline:

```
s1 = m.addVars(indices, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='s1')
s2 = m.addVars(indices, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='s2')

# Some constraints with s1 and s2

c1 = m.addVars(indices, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='c1')
c2 = m.addVars(indices, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='c2')

for i in range(M):
    for j in range(N):
        m.addGenConstrPWL(s1[i, j], c1[i, j], X, Y)
        m.addGenConstrPWL(s1[i, j], c1[i, j], X, Y)

# also need to add constraints with c1 and c2 in the future
```

So my question is it expected that PWL constraints would cause such a drop in performance, and can I do something to improve it?

Comment: It is not shocking that PWL constraints would slow the solver significantly. Internally they may result in the addition of a bunch of binary variables and related constraints. As to how to improve performance, there is not enough information to say much.

Comment: Is the feasible region convex? Convex models are much easier to solve than nonconvex models.